# Xcode can't find imported header files

Tags: xcode, header, import

I've used other IDE's in the past but am new to Xcode. I'm trying to bring in a bunch of C code from an open source project.  I've imported them into a new Group and the .c files all show up under Implementation Files and the full list of files shows up in the Groups/Files group as well as my project directory in the finder. When I try to include or import one of these header files, code completion even works so I know Xcode is seeing them. But then when I go to build it says "no such file or directory".

How can I get these files to import into my code?

Answer (score 2):

I still have complier errors but I at least figured out this one.  The problem was that I was doing:

```
#import <lib/myheader.h>
```

and apparently that is only for system header files. What I needed to do was use quotes:

```
#import "lib/myheader.h"
```